# Yarn doesn't install dependency in candy-machine-ui

Tags: dependencies, create-react-app, hadoop-yarn, solana, candy-machine

Wanted to start candymachine-ui yarn doesn't install it's last dependency called @material-ui/icons [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATumt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, it's the problem with your Yarn version. Try these steps:-

- run `npm uninstall yarn`
- Delete all the `node_modules` folders in the candymachine_ui directory.
- run `npm install -g yarn`
- run `yarn install` in the dir

**If none of them works, run one of these commands**:-

- `yarn add @material-ui/icons`
  **OR**
  `npm install @material-ui/icons`

It should then work:)